# TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_url'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I'm running the below function code to terminate the process after a certain time. I'm getting error about argument pass but I passed the argument but still, I'm getting error can anyone solve this and explain what's wrong with the code.

```
def main(new_url):
    while True:
        ssl.match_hostfname = lambda cert, hostname: True

        ## Useragents Added 'using random user agent' library
        software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
        operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]
        user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=100)
        # Get Random User Agent String.
        user_agent = user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()
        req = Request(new_url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
        html = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
        text1 = get_text(html)
        final_text.append(text1)
        time.sleep(20)
        break

    return text1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We create a Process
    action_process = Process(target=main)

    # The process time limit is 10 secons.
    action_process.start()
    action_process.join(timeout=10)

    # We terminate the process.
    action_process.terminate()
```

Comment: The **full** traceback would be helpful

Comment: Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_url'

Comment: Not here... Please [edit] that into the question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments of the main function like below, define new_url in the args.

```
action_process = Process(target=main, args=(new_url,))
```

Comment: when  I added args=(new_url, ) it says **Unresolved reference 'new_url'**

Comment: new_url must be defined and must have a url value
eg:

`new_url = "https://google.com"`
`action_process = Process(target=main, args=(new_url,))`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `main` takes one position argument (`new_url`), however, you are not passing in that argument. As per the multiprocessing documentation for the [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) class, you can specify `args`

e.g.

```py
action_process = Process(target=main, args=("new_url"))
```

Comment: when I added args = ("new_url") it says **Expected type 'Tuple[Any, ...]', got 'str' instead**

Comment: That's a different issue, we assumed here that you understood your own code. `new_url` was a placeholder. I assume you're using `urllib`, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request).